# What is that Teradata? syntax for a subquery aliased with a parameter (can't find a name of ref for this)

Tags: sql, teradata

it goes like this:

```
SELECT LOOKUP.LOOKUP_ID 
FROM (
    SELECT INNER_ID FROM 
        (
         SELECT max(INNER_ID) INNER_ID 
         FROM INNER_TABLE 
        ) INNER_QUERY 
      ) LOOKUP (LOOKUP_ID)
```

It's a legacy code - I inherited - in Teradata, still runs in TD 16.20, but this is the only instance I have run into something so strange. And why would you key it like this - is another question.

Comment: why do you have a `(LOOKUP_ID) ` at the end? that is no valid sql code

Comment: @nbk - this is actually valid, at least in Teradata.  It is an incredibly confusing way to alias columns in a derived table.

Comment: Not only in Teradata. As far as I know this is standard SQL, and I don't find it confusing either. PostgreSQL supports it. SQL Server supports it... It is more common with values clauses, but can be used on derived tables, too.

Comment: @nbk: It's plain Standard SQL syntax

Comment: "_Conforms to SQL-2016
The following features outside Core SQL-2016 are used:
F591, Derived tables_", according to https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well these are subqueries in the `FROM` clause. Such subqueries are also known as "derived tables".

The innermost subquery is

```
(
  SELECT MAX(inner_id) inner_id 
  FROM inner_table 
) inner_query
```

Here we select the maximum `inner_id` and call this value `inner_id` again. We reference this one-row query result by the alias `inner_query`.

The next subquery is

```
(
  SELECT inner_id
  FROM ( <above subquery> ) inner_query 
) lookup (lookup_id)
```

We select the aforementioned maximum `inner_id` that is still called `inner_id` and call the one-row result set now `lookup` and the value `lookup_id`.

At last we select that value

```
SELECT lookup.lookup_id FROM ( ... ) lookup (lookup_id);
```

We would get the same result with a mere

```
SELECT MAX(inner_id) AS lookup_id 
FROM inner_table;
```

of course.

Maybe you are just unfamiliar with the alias name syntax for tables and columns:

```
FROM mytable table_alias
```

or

```
FROM mytable table_alias (col1_alias, col2_alias, ...)
```

Comment: that really doesn't explain the problem, he has as his code runs for example in sql server or ppstgres, so his original query is faulty, code his code presented

Comment: @nbk: They only say that this is an old Teradata query and they are surprised by the syntax. That's all. There is no problem. They just wanted the syntax explained. Or is there something I have missed?

Comment: @thorsten, exactly